# MapInfo 64bit Statusbar

Tags: mapinfo, vba

I'm working on an application that involves VB6 and MapInfo. I have two sets of application, one 32-bit (MapInfo 10.5) and one 64-bit (MapInfo 2021) with nearly the same set of code.

The 32-bit works flawlessly, the 64 bit on the other hand, has a ton of problems. The biggest being that the MapInfo status bar does not change upon mouse movement in the map, leaving SetStatusText uncalled and messing up more processes down the line.

This, combined with the fact that the HandleToolButton, another responder code, works inconsistently has led me to believe that the responder is the problem.

This is the setup for the responder:

```
Public theResponder As Object

Private Function Set_MapInfo() As Boolean
   Debug.Print ("Set_MapInfo")
   On Error GoTo ErrTrap
   Set MapInfo = CreateObject("MapInfo.Application")
   Set_MapInfo = True
   Exit Function
ErrTrap:
     Set_MapInfo = False
     End Function

Public Sub InitializeMapInfoConnection()
        Debug.Print ("InitializeMapConnection")
        Screen.MousePointer = 11
        On Error GoTo mErr
        
        If Set_MapInfo = False Then
            Set MapInfo = CreateObject("MapInfo.Application.x64")
        End If
        
        MapInfo.Do "Set Application Window " & FrmMainWin.hWnd
        
        Set theResponder = New MIResponder
        MapInfo.SetCallback theResponder
        
        DoEvents
        MapWinID = 0                           
        MapInfo.RunMenuCommand M_TOOLS_SELECTOR
        Screen.MousePointer = 0
        Exit Sub

mErr:
        MsgBox Err.Description, 64, "MapInfo Connection..."
        Screen.MousePointer = 0
        Exit Sub

End Sub
```

This is the code the responder is supposed to be calling (It's in a file called "MIResponder.cls"):

```
'**********************************************************************
''  This is the source of the problem. It's not working.
'   SetStatusText
'       This is a standard method that MapInfo looks for in its Callback
'       object. If MapInfo finds this method in the Callback object, it
'       will get called automatically every time the text in MapInfo's
'       status bar text changes. The string passed in is a tab-delimited
'       string containing each of the status bar "Fields", i.e. - the
'       first field is the zoom, scale, or cursor location, the second field
'       is the editable layer, etc.
'
'**********************************************************************
Public Sub SetStatusText(ByVal statusText As String)
        Debug.Print ("SetStatusText")
        Dim newText As String
         If InStr(1, statusText, "JPïw", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
         statusText = ""
         End If
        newText = GetField(statusText, vbTab, 1)
        GetCurrentScale = newText
        '--MsgBox GetCurrentScale
        If newText <> "" Then FrmMainWin.Label1(0).Caption = " " & newText & " "
        
        newText = GetField(statusText, vbTab, 2)
        If newText <> "" Then FrmMainWin.Label1(1).Caption = " " & newText & " "
        
        newText = GetField(statusText, vbTab, 3)
        If newText <> "" Then
               FrmMainWin.Label1(2).Caption = " " & newText & " "
               If Not UCase(newText) = "NONE" Then
                  FrmMainWin.MainTab.Tools("ID_UnselectAll").Enabled = True
               End If
        End If
        
End Sub
```

What do I need to do to resolve this?